# git archive including uncommitted modified files

Tags: git

so `git archive --format=tar HEAD` will give me a tar archive of the latest commit on the current branch. Is there a version that would include local modifications to tracked files that have not yet been committed?

Comment: You could always just make a commit, export your archive, then do a mixed reset back to the previous commit to restore your working copy to the same state it was in before you committed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The git way is to commit everything. Remember, branches are cheap.

```
git checkout -b intermediate-releases/20140414
git commit -m 'Wibble wobble wubble'
```

Then restore your working copy — I don't know to do that reliably but I'm sure there's a way. Now you can make an archive of the new branch's tip:

```
git archive intermediate-releases/20140414 | gzip >20140414.tgz
```

If you really don't want to keep track of that archive (but why not?), you could make a stash, which has the advantage of making it really easy to restore the working copy.

```
git stash
git archive 'stash@{0}' | gzip >whatever.tgz
git stash pop
```

If you absolutely don't want to make any change to the working copy, you can use `git ls-files` to retrieve the list of files and archive these.

```
git ls-files HEAD | tar -czf whaterver.tgz -T -
```